# How to stop the app in background when user settings changed

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, nsuserdefaults, nslocalizedstring

I've implemented the settings.bundle to give the user the choice of selecting one of three possible languages. When pressing the Home-button to quit the app remains in background. If I change now in the settings the language for my app and touch the app-icon the app remains in the last language. I have to stop the app by double-clicking the Home-button and wipe it off. With the following restart the app launches in the desired language. How can I do that "stop" done in the background if the user-settings are changed? Or how can I force to reload the views when entering foreground?

Comment: Read the documentation on UIApplicationDelegate and UIViewController.  There are numerous notifications sent to your app when it returns to the foreground or when a view becomes active.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not solving my problem. If the app returns to the foreground it is too late. I have tried the NSNotificationCenter but this will checked when the app is still launched and I need the check when the app is in background.